# For cycle returning [object Object]

Tags: javascript, rest, object, stringify

I want to create a simple table to store the responses in. A book can have multiple authors so the authors object is an array. Author has two fields(first_name and last_name)
I know I have to stringify the object but I do not know where to use it.

```
function tableCreation(response) {
    let final ="<table>";
    final += "<th>ID</th><th>Title</th><th>Publisher</th><th>Author</th>";
    for (let i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
        final += `<tr><td>${response[i].id}</td><td>${response[i].title}</td><td>${response[i].publisher}</td><td>${response[i].author}</td></tr>`;
                 }
    final +="</table>";
    document.getElementById("field").innerHTML = final;
}
```

This displays the table like this:

```
ID | Title | Publisher |    Author
1     NAME     NAME     [object Object]
```

Comment: Looks like `author` is not just a string, but another object.   It's maybe something like `author.name` ..

Comment: `${response[i].author.first_name} ${response[i].author.last_name}`

Comment: After inserting the above code it changes to ```undefined ```

Comment: What do you get if you  -> `console.log(response)` inside that function?

Comment: I get this:  ```  [{id": 1,"title": "name","publisher": "name","author": [{"id":1,"first_name": "name", "last_name": "name"
            }],
          }] ```

Comment: In that case `Author` is an array, if your only interested in the first one, you could put `${response[i].author[0].first_name} ${response[i].author[0].last_name}`

Comment: This works for one author thanks, I know in my case it is only one, but what if there were multiple authors?

Comment: You will need to re-think your layout if there are multiple ones.  How you do that, is up to you.  One idea is you could loop an put `<br/>` between each one.

Answer (score 0):

This is because response[I].author is an object.
Replace it with ${response[i].author.first_name} ${response[i].author.last_name}

Comment: Check the comment to my comment, I don't think the object is in the shape the OP thinks.

Answer (score 0):

Thats because you are trying to print an object, while you actually want to print JSON, you can do it like so:

```
JSON.stringify(response[i].author)
```

The code would look like this:

```
function tableCreation(response) {
    let final ="<table>";
    final += "<th>ID</th><th>Title</th><th>Publisher</th><th>Author</th>";
    for (let i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
        final += `<tr><td>${response[i].id}</td><td>${response[i].title}</td><td>${response[i].publisher}</td><td>${JSON.stringify(response[i].author)}</td></tr>`;
                 }
    final +="</table>";
    document.getElementById("field").innerHTML = final;
}
```

**Edit**

You can pass a second argument to `JSON.stringigy()` as an array of fields to print (the rest will be excluded) so if you want `first_name` and `last_name`

```
//outputs: {"first_name":"name","last_name":"lname"}
JSON.stringify(response[i].author, ["first_name", "last_name"])
```

Comment: That will certainly show the object, but it's going to look a bit ugly in that table layout.. :)

Comment: It works like this but I get it in the following code in the author header ```[{"id":1,"first_name":"name","last_name":"lname"}]``` and I only want the first_name value and the last_name to be displayed, not like a whole json, is there a way to do that?